# How to solve TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND (0x8002802B) error loading old DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, vb6-migration, regsvr32

I am trying to use old VB6-made DLLs in a VS2017 solution, but one of them started to fail last week.

I have registered them (regsvr32), added the references in the solution, and tried using the methods inside them.

Everything was going OK when I closed my VS2017 for lunch break on Friday, and when I tried resuming my work one of the DLLs started misbehaving.

The mentioned DLL throws a **TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND** error like it is not even there and, obviously, I can't access the methods inside its class.

Location is not an issue here (tried using it from System32 and SysWOW64 with no luck), and it is still showing the

> Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference
>   "prjPermisos". Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B
>   (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))

warning (not even an Error, but the IDE is still not letting me use the DLL.)

My code is as simple as can be:

```
prjPermisos.clsCarPermisos carPermisos = new prjPermisos.clsCarPermisos();
carPermisos.CargaPermisos(ref oUsuario, ref sError);   //<--"are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" error
```

Cleaned (both with the IDE and manually) the solution, Rebuilt, Built the solution and still nothing.

I am positive I am missing something here, I just don't know what.

Any help or guidance to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you, or have you, tried running VS2017 as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, same error. Changed the target to x86 as well.

Comment: And delete and re-add the reference? And in addition to clean, have you deleted the Debug, Release and Obj folders?

Comment: Several times. Unregistered and reregistered every time.
Deleted all the folders you mentioned manually.

Comment: And manually creating the C# proxy using tlbimp? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer

Comment: That I haven't tried. A second, please.

Comment: You can also ensure that ref oUsuario, ref sError are both NOT NULL, and ensure you can still call the DLL from VB6 and ensure that the DLL is not missing it's dependencies and try adding a Task.Delay(2000) between the calls...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188295/discussion-between-murray-foxcroft-and-tono-perez).

Answer (score -2):

SOLVED. Let's thank Murray Foxcroft for the idea.

Ran and recompiled the DLL project, replaced the faulting dll and everything was working again. -_-

Comment: Ideally you should add a lot more specific information to this answer, to help the next person who comes along with a similar problem.